# How to use Process.Start() in .netcore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to run an exe which is there in the location which I am using as Working directory and the name of the file is same as used in FileName. still when I run this I am getting "The system cannot find the file specified.".
When I see the process object I see so many exceptions of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.
Any help would be really helpful here.
I am working on .NetCore

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\MyData\APM\REL-431\Source\Upgrade Utilities\Meridium.DbUtility.CalibDeviceMappingsUpgradeUtility\bin\Debug";
startInfo.FileName = "Meridium.DbUtility.CalibDeviceMappingsUpgradeUtility.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "V4030100_BASE MIADMIN MIADMIN"; //Change these parameters based on your test DB

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: What does `File.Exists(Path.Combine(startInfo.WorkingDirectory, startInfo.FileName))` give you? true or false?

Comment: Also check what `File.Exists(startInfo.FileName)` tells you. [WorkingDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=net-5.0) affects how relative paths in `FileName` are treated, based on the [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-5.0) property. .NET Old and .NET Core use different defaults, so in .NET Old your code would try to start a file in the `WorkingDirectory` while in .NET Core, in application's current directory

Comment: To avoid confusion use an absolute path for `FileName`. Use command names *only* if you want to execute a program in the PATH

Comment: File.Exists(Path.Combine(startInfo.WorkingDirectory, startInfo.FileName)) was giving me true but File.Exists(startInfo.FileName) was giving false. Now I changed FileNAme to an absolute path and  File.Exists(startInfo.FileName) gives true now but still error is same